Item Fulfillment - Inventory Detail when setting itemreceive to false
Essentially, I have an existing fulfillment that needs to get updated based on what actually gets shipped from the warehouse. If non of an item are shipped, I need to mark the checkbox itemreceive aka "Fulfill" as false. I'm doing this via suitescript 2.1. When I mark this field, I get the error "Please configure the inventory detail in line 3 of the item list." I thought perhaps this was an issue with the way I was looping through the lines, but when I tried setting a specific IF explicitly, I still received the same error. Here is the relevant code:
                childRecord.selectLine({
                sublistId: 'item',
                line: 3
            });
            childRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'itemreceive',
                value: false
            });
            childRecord.commitLine({
                sublistId: 'item',
                line: 3
            });

Is there something else I need to be doing with the inventory detail to allow this to set?
